# Conectar a github codigo que ya esta en produccion

Tags: git, github

Buen dia ! Soy nuevo en el tema de git y github
Tengo un proyecto de Wordpress que ya esta en produccion en un servidor (de Kinsta)
y quiero creaer un git para poder clonarlo y hacer cambios en local y diferentes ramas!
Pero no se como conectar el codigo que ya tengo en produccion a github sin que afecte lo que tengo ya en produccion.
Si pudieran orientarme de como puedo realizarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Primero tienes que subir tu proyecto a un repositorio de github para eso debes:

1. Ubicate en la carpeta donde tienes tu proyecto, por ejemplo : `cd miProyecto/`
2. Inicia un repositorio de git alli con el comando: `git init`
3. Ve a github y crea un nuevo repositorio:

- Recuerda que es buena practica tener un archivo README.md que se mostrara en la pagina ofical de tu proyecto de github asi que deberias crearlo y editarlo (si es que no lo tienes) en tu carpeta del proyecto y luego hacer un commit para guardar los cambios.

4. Debes de crear un origen del repositorio remoto que creaste para que este se conecte con el local: `git remote add origin git@github.com:Usuario/Proyecto.git`

- El url varia segun tu usuario, tu repositorio y tambien si usas un llave ssh para conectarlo o si usas el protocolo https.

5. Debes de cambiar el nombre de tu rama principal a 'main' ya que el repositorio remoto (github al crear un repositorio nuevo te lo crea con la rapa principal con nombre main), puedes saltarte este paso si tu rama principal tiene el nombre de main, si no es asi entonces: `git branch -M main` eso cambiara tu rama principal a main.
6. Ahora solamente debes de enviar tu rama principal de tu repo local a el repo remoto (github): `git push origin main`
   De esa manera creas un repositorio remoto de github conectado a tu proyecto pero debes de entender que todos los cambios que hagas a el repo local no se modificara en el repositorio de github a menos de que hagas un push y si modificas algo en github esto no se modificara en tu local a menos de que hagas un pull.

Ahora si quieres hacer experimentos sin que afecte lo que ya tienes en github o produccion simplemente para hacer cambios, es una buena practica crear una nueva rama y alli hacer los cambios que quieras: `git branch nombreRama`

- Si quieres fucionar los cambios de la rama nueva y enviarlos a produccion deberias hacer un merge.
- Si quieres enviar tu rama nueva a github puedes hacer: `git push origin nombreRama`

Si lo que quieres es clonar tu proyecto y hacer los cambios que quieras en la rama que sea puedes ubicarte en la carpeta que quieras clonarlo y alli hacer un: `git clone git@github.com:Usuario/Proyecto.git` obviamente debes de cambiar la url por la de tu proyecto, entonces de esa manera hacer los cambios que quieras y nada se vera modificado en local ni en github.